# pdfLaTeX Font shape undefined using DejaVuSans

Tags: fonts, pdftex, installing-fonts

For about a week I am unable to include the "DejaVu Sans" font into my pdflatex in order to use it. My document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fontfamily{DejaVuSans}
\selectfont
\begin{document}
Some text...
\end{document}
```

In the console I am getting this message:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/DejaVuSans/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 4.
(./untitled-2.aux) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./untitled-2.aux)
```

untitled-2 would be the name of the document. The "pdftex.map" file lists the desired font in different encodings and font shapes as I understand. The related .pfb files are found in the in the texlive directories as well.
When I use "pdftex testfont", I can choose "DejaVuSans-tlf-t1--base" without problems and I can create an (working) output table out of it.

Any suggestions what I did wrong?

Comment: what happens, when you add `\usepackage{lmodern}`?

Comment: There is no difference, the output as well as the console message are the same

Comment: check the instructions on this page: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/dejavusans/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the fd-file is `T1DejaVuSans-TLF.fd` (see e.g. http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/dejavu/tex). This means that the name of the family is `DejaVuSans-TLF`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\fontfamily{DejaVuSans-TLF}
\selectfont

Some text...
\end{document}
```